# How can I remove not existing images in magento 1.9.2

Tags: magento-1.9

How can I remove not existing images from magento. In the database  have images but file is not exist. I want deleted this images from database, because they show on product page with "NoImage" image. I wrote script which export entity_id and not existing path to file.

This script return following result:

```
entity_id   image_path
178559  /catalog/product/i/m/image_1.jpg
178559  /catalog/product/i/m/image_2.jpg
281136  /catalog/product/i/m/image_122.jpg
173563  /catalog/product/i/m/image_121.jpg
8163    /catalog/product/i/m/image_12.jpg
```

How can I do that programmatically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create remove.php file inside your magento root with the following contents:

```
<?php
include('app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$api = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_media_api');
foreach($products as $product){
  $images = $api->items($product->getId());
  foreach($images as $img){
   if(!file_exists(Mage::getBaseDir('media').'/catalog/product'.$img['file']))
     $api->remove($product->getId(),$img['file']);                                                                                                                                 
  }   
}
```

then execute it via command line

```
php remove.php
```

might take a while if you have many skus

Comment: I have a question about this. This script is very slowly. I try to get all files from mysql table (catalog_product_entity_media_gallery) and check file exist, this accelerates the process, but I have more than ~40 000 files which is not existed  and with **$app->remote()** the executing time is 2 seconds for file. Is It possible to delete record only in database in this table catalog_product_entity_media_gallery.